# Google Chart: Error not an array

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm creating a google chart, and try to insert data:

```
//This is true
console.log(Array.isArray(data_arr));

//Uncaught error: Not an array 
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    data.addRows(data_arr);
```

I don't get it, why does it not work?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

When using `arrayToDataTable`, you must provide an array as an argument to the function call.  Since you are not providing an array, you need to use the regular DataTable constructor:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```